# How I use the put() method for Maps in Maps

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

this is my Map in Maps I created

```
private static Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> directory = new HashMap<>();
```

and I want to know how I use the put() method for this above.

I tried this for example:

```
directory.put(5,"Test1","Test2");
```

but this is not correct. I get the following message by eclipse:

```
The method put(Integer, Map<String,String>) in the type Map<Integer,Map<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (int, String, String)
```

But I have to hold on to the guidelines for the university. There is a JUnitTest and there is also the put method. Just look how they did this:

```
addEntry(1, "Name", "Dall", "FirstName", "Karl", "phoneNr", "4711");
```

and thats my addEntry Method from the university

```
public static void addEntry(int nrP, String... attrValPairs) throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Comment: You use it the same as normal. put() takes two arguments, in your case the first is an Integer, the second is a Map.

Comment: Are you sure you want a map of maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would implement it like this

```
private static final Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> directory = new HashMap<>();

public static void put(Integer key1, String key2, String value) {
    Map<String, String> map = directory.get(key1);
    if (map == null)
        directory.put(key1, map = new HashMap<>());
    map.put(key2, value);
}
```

Comment: I have to hold on the guidelines from the university. You see my post above (edited). But I think this is allowed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Yours is a nested `Map`, so you need to have a `Map` object in the value of the outer `Map`:

```
if(!directory.containsKey(5)) {
    directory.put(5, new HashMap<>());
}
directory.get(5).put("Test1", "Test2");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private static Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> directory = new HashMap<>();
```

This accepts 2 arguments `Integer` and `Map`

So you can only put `Integer` and `Map` but here `directory.put(5,"Test1","Test2");` you are putting 3 arguements `Integer`,`String` and `String`

Hence this error `The method put(Integer, Map<String,String>) in the type Map<Integer,Map<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (int, String, String)`

To solve your problem I would suggest you to create another map like this

```
Map<String, String> directory1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Now put the Strings in this map first like this

directory1.put("Test1","Test2");

and now you can use this

```
directory.put(5,directory1);
```